# Android Google Authentication With Firebase And Multiple Cloud Projects

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

### Is it possible to use Google Sign In with a web client id, that belongs to a different google cloud project than the one that is used for firebase?

We have two cloud projects

- `project-main`

  Used for most of our own infrastructure.
- `project-mobile`

  Used for firebase and mobile (android).

I'd like configure Google Sign In to use a web client id created for `project-main` in order to authorize android clients using [GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.requestIdToken(String)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.html#requestIdToken(java.lang.String)) at our backend. The app's gms Gradle plugin is pointing to `project-mobile` by using the downloaded `google-services.json` from firebase. How can this be done?

I found a post titled [*Working with multiple Firebase projects in an Android app*](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html). Unfortunately it did not solve the issue for me. The client fails to authorize at google.

PS: When using the default web client id, authorization works. But this is not what I want - as the default client id is created for `project-mobile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the SHA fingerprint from the firebase console config.